# Site not loading over SSL with IE8

Tags: apache, ssl, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp

After finally tracking down the cause of my SSL certs being rejected in IE8 (SNI), I fixed the issue but now the site doesn't load at all (Times out eventually).

I'm not really sure how to diagnose this as all the SSL validation tools check out OK, it works in all other browsers, and Google turns up nothing useful.

The site is: https://api.atlanticpharmaceutical.ca/test.php

The site works in other browsers in IE, and IE loads other HTTPS sites fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the config options one of the SSL validators told me to add, specifically:

```
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP
```